# Select with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this in my database:

```
table styles

style_id    style
1           rock
2           blues
3           jazz
etc...

table user_styles

user_id    style_id
1          1
1          2
2          3
etc...
```

I want do this:

- If user_styles for user_id(ej. 1) is empty then show the table styles in a select for user to select. If is not empty, show the results for the user_id (ej. 1).
- Insert/update the options selected into de table user_styles.

Comment: is there anything you've tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes, please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Check for s.style for a particular user using below mysql query:
"SELECT style FROM styles s JOIN user_styles us ON s.style_id = us.style_id WHERE us.user_id = ?, [UserId]"

2: if you are getting no value, then go for showing all styles present in style table in a dropdown, allow user to select and submit.
onSubmit, insert the style detail into user_style table.
3: else show the style for the user.

This is the logic best comes to my mind now. You can also try many other ways as well. I do not see any logical or programatical issue here.